# How can I call a constructor properly in this case?

Tags: java, constructor, field

I'm trying to call a constructor properly dealing with 3 different class but I'm not able to do it

```
public class B {

private final A a;

public B(A a) {
     this.a = a;
}
private final C c = new C(a);
}
```

I have the error "variable a might not have been initialized", I know a way to do it by putting a second argument in the B constructor and calling it in the main class B but is there any other way ?

Comment: Why do you need a second argument in the B constructor? Just declare `private final C c;` and then in the constructor, `c = new C(a);`.

Comment: Just wondering: do you need further information, or is your question resolved (if so, consider accepting one of the answers).

Comment: Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
public class B {

    private final A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        c = new C(a);
    }
    private final C c;
}
```

The reason yours doesn't work is that initializers at declaration are executed before constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
private final C c = new C(a);
```

There you can avoid that "conflict" of order, by simply assigning `c` **also** in your constructor:

```
public B(A a) {
     this.a = a;
     this.c = new C(a);
}
```

Sure, when you can define your fields right at the declaration, that simplifies a lot. But sometimes, doing it in the constructor just can't be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the value in the ctor

```
public class B {
    private final A a;
    private final C c;

    public B(final A a) {
         this.a = a;
         this.c = new C(a)
    }
}
```